# How to configure and use qemu-guest-agent in Ubuntu 12.04? My main aim is to get the IP address of guest VM from Host machine

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, qemu

In the documentation it is not very clear that how to install and use qemu-guest-agent in Ubuntu 12.04.

So can anyone help me out ?

http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Qemu_guest_agent

It is a daemon program running inside the domain which is supposed to help management applications with executing functions which need assistance of the guest OS. I want to know the IP address of the guest VM using guest-network-get-interfaces qemu-guest-agent command.

Is there any other way to find IP address of guest VM ?

arp -an, arpwatch ,echo syslog | grep $mac_address is not useful in my scenario ?

Comment: the guest agent can be contacted via the monitor commands, all the commands are prefixed with `guest-`. Not sure abut the IP, in oVirt it's done by another agent

Comment: If your main aim is to get the IP address, then see http://serverfault.com/a/676257/140905

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. First of all install latest version of libvirt-bin(>=1.0.0) on the host system. Installing libvirt-bin(>=1.0.0) on Ubuntu12.04 is itself a challenge because of dependencies.This link may help to do so: 
   https://tad-do.net/2013/02/22/testing-new-libvirt-features-on-ubuntu-12-04/

   Then execute following commands on host:

   ```
   mkdir -p /var/lib/libvirt/qemu/channel/target
   chown -R libvirt-qemu:kvm /var/lib/libvirt/qemu/channel
   ```
2. Add the following to the bottom of /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/libvirt-qemu:

   ```
   /var/lib/libvirt/qemu/channel/target/* rw,
   ```
3. Install qemu-guest-agent in guest VM.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install qemu-guest-agent
   ```
4. virsh edit VMNAME and add following lines in the devices:

   ```
   <channel type="unix">
     <source mode="bind"/>
     <target type="virtio" name="org.qemu.guest_agent.0"/>
   </channel>
   ```
5. Shutdown and start the VM and execute following command to get the IP Address. There are many other things which can be done using guest-agent.

   ```
   virsh qemu-agent-command VMNAME '{"execute":"guest-network-get-interfaces"}'
   ```

References:http://wiki.stoney-cloud.org/wiki/Qemu_Guest_Agent_Integration